# Java Eclipse - Search Specific Data From Text File

Tags: java, eclipse, text-files

So all I need to do is be able to search for rooms from a text file, and bring up any matches that relate to what I searched. The code runs fine through the questions (room type, min and max price, balcony, and lounge), but at the end, all it does is take the first room in the text file, AND change the values to the ones I searched, (Which obviously I just want to find rooms, not change anything about them). Not sure where I've went wrong and why it only finds the first room and changes it when I don't want.  any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
private static void reserveRoom() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);    
        Scanner ROOMS = new Scanner (new FileReader("rooms.txt"));

        int roomnumber = ROOMS.nextInt();
        String roomtype = ROOMS.next();
        double roomprice = ROOMS.nextDouble();
        Boolean hasbalcony = ROOMS.nextBoolean();
        Boolean haslounge = ROOMS.nextBoolean();

        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("--Seach Rooms--" + "\n");

        System.out.println("Room Type (Single/Double/Suite):");
        roomtype = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(" ");


        System.out.println("Minimum Price: ");
        roomprice = s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("Highest Price: ");
        roomprice = s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("Balcony Preferred?: ");
        hasbalcony = s.nextBoolean();
        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("Has Lounge?: ");
        haslounge = s.nextBoolean();

        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.println("Searching...");

        System.out.println(" ");

        System.out.printf("Room Number: %s,  Room Type: %s,   Room Price: £%.2f,   Has Balcony: %s, Has Lounge: %s" + "\n", roomnumber, roomtype, roomprice, hasbalcony, haslounge);

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- " + "\n");
```

Comment: There are no loops to make it continuous. Use a for/while loop

Comment: I have a do while loop inserted well  before the above line of my code (it's for the menu interface) and it makes it loop back to the menu when I'm done (it works fine). So I need to create another loop at this part too?

Comment: @user3632894 Sorry for the bother but I'm pretty new to Java, where exactly would my loop go in the code? And which type of loop should I use?

Comment: Gonna bump, I've tried loops and still no luck. All I need it to do is print rooms from the rooms.txt file based on the search preferences I've put in. but all it's doing is printing the first room AND its value are set to what I've typed in, when I want the rooms to keep their own value. Anyone know?

Comment: I am not sure about your requirement, but I am not able to see your comparison logic. You have read a few lines and reused those variable to take input from user. My suggestion is to use some database to store data and then find using queries.